# Particle System Grass on Animated Object

Tags: animation, particles

I have a particle hair system distributing my grass models across a cylinder ground plane. The rotation orientation axis is set to the normals of the cylinder ground plane however when I animate the rotation of the cylinder the particles do not follow the same rotation and they fall flat. I need to use the hair system instead of an emitter so I can use turbulent forcefield to create wind. Any idea how to lock particle systems to the rotation of the ground plane?

[image: FullScene]
[image: 0 rotation]
[image: rotated]
[image: particle system]

Comment: "normally" this should work. Can u pls provide blend file?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that my issue was entirely the Orientation Axis in the Rotation tab. Changed it to Velocity and my issue disappeared.